# Calculating Distance and Velocity from FMCW Radar Data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm working on processing FMCW radar data in MATLAB for a project, and I need to calculate the distance and velocity of a detected object. The dataset I have is called 'adcData' and is structured in three dimensions:

The first dimension (columns) contains sampled values for a single ramp.
The second dimension (rows) indexes the ramp number.
The third dimension represents the antenna number.

The assignment says:
"You're tasked with generating the spectrum for each ramp for both antennas and storing this in a variable named FFT_R. Additionally, you're supposed to create a frequency vector Fr and use it to calculate the distance vector R."

```
 F_c = 76.5e9;     
    B = 300e6;         
    lambda = 3e8 / F_c; 
    d = lambda / 2;   
    T_rampe = 64e-6;   
    T_PRI = 70e-6;     
    N_Rampen = 128;    
    F_Sample = 4e6;    
    N_Samples = T_rampe * F_Sample; 
    
    %b.)
    t = 0:1/F_Sample:T_rampe-1/F_Sample;
    x_ant1 = adcData(:, 1, 1);
    x_ant2 = adcData(:, 1, 2);
N_Samples_per_Ramp = size(adcData, 1);


FFTR = fft(adcData, [], 1);

FFTR = fftshift(FFTR, 1);

df = F_Sample / N_Samples_per_Ramp; 
Fr = (-N_Samples_per_Ramp/2:N_Samples_per_Ramp/2-1) * df;

c = 3e8; 
R = c* Fr / (2 * B) ;
```

The formula for R is not correct since the assignment states that I'm supposed to calculate R, which is also the only way that makes sense, by taking into account the FFTR I calculated a few lines prior. Unfortunately, I can't find the formula or the way to do that in any of my course materials.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Besides searching in your course materials have you considered to google this subject? One of the first hits brings you here [(Texas Instruments) FMCW Radars - Module 1 : Range Estimation](https://www.ti.com/video/5415203482001)